# Check if $X_n$ converges to a random variable and finding its distribution

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, normal-distribution, weak-convergence

The (homework) question says that $X_n$ is a random variable with $\mathrm{Normal}(1/n, 1/n)$. It asks then, if $X_n$ converges in distribution to a random variable $X$, and if yes, what is the distribution of this $X$?

I am aware that this involves the use of the Weak Law of Large Numbers, but I do not know how I proceed further than the theorem (i.e I don't know how I practically apply it to a problem like this). I haven't been able to proceed further than recognizing the theorem to be used.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: AFAIK this is unrelated to any law of large numbers. You just need to use any characterization of weak convergence of measures, see my hint below.

Comment: $X_n$ has same distribution as $\frac 1 {\sqrt n} (\frac  1 n +X)$ where $X\sim N(0,1)$ and the latter converges a.s  to $0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm can you explain the math? I don't get how you arrived there

Answer (score 0):

HINT: let $F_n$ the distribution function of $X_n$, then to answer your question it is enough to check if $F_n\to F$ pointwise to a distribution in each of it continuity points.

But as the variance goes to zero then $F$ just can be a degenerate distribution, indeed it just can be the case that $F= \mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty )}$, now check if it is the case that $F_n\to F$ at every continuity point of $F$ to finish.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm not however, aware of what a 'degenerate distribution' is, nor am I able to grasp the concept of it.

Comment: @PranavR a degenerated distribution is when it variance is zero. Anyway I added the definition of $F$